# Hang punching bag in finished basement

Tags: wood, structural

I have a 40lb punching bag that I want to hang for kids but I want to do this in a way that I can upsize the bag as needed.  My basement is finished, and I'm *ok* with cutting out some ceiling drywall to do this but I'm wondering if it's OK to do it without removing drywall.

What I was thinking was a [2/4]x[4/6] would be bolted to 2 floor joists through the drywall.  I would countersink the top so I can put the bolt through without needing to push into drywall above.

Am I better off just cutting out the drywall or is this sufficient?  Are there modifications I can make to improve this?

If I were to cut out the drywall my plan would be to put a 4x4 between the joists and then another 2x4 bolted to that from underneath, so that it was flush with joists. (please correct me if that's no good either).

In the image, the dark blue are floor joists, brown is a [2/4]x[4/6], light blue are additional 2x4's that I'm not sure are needed.

[image]

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance but what is a  [2/4]x[4/6]?

Comment: @Jack sorry, that's stuff I use from my day job. It's a short way of writing, 2x4 Or 2x6 or 4x4 or 4x6

Comment: You would rather trash your basement than buy a free standing bag?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be bolting the supports over the drywall. You will get movement back and forth from the bag and that movement will start to compact the drywall and eventually loosed the supports.

Think about installing a 4x4 between two joists with joist hangers. Then drill a hole through the 4x4 and install a 1/2" eye bolt and hold it in place with nuts and washers.

Comment: I have seen this done but the vibration shreds the dry wall. The best option would to open the drywall and add cross bracing 1 bay past on each side so you have 3 or 4 cross braces the with of the bag support. Then a 2x4 on each side directly to the joists (Lag bolts) and new Sheetrock between. I think this is what jack is closing on but without the cross supports any hits to the bag will really shake the floor adding cross bracing then perpendicular 2x4 to attach the 4x4 is what we did in a gym 10 heavy bags, and 10 punching bags with a book keeping office above , this dampened the vibration.